# Page redirect using regular expression to find 3 digit number at end of query string using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, regex, wordpress

I have this redirect working except for a way to get the number at the end of the query string `ex: /my-page/?ref=236` The first page is identified using PHP with a conditional (in WordPress), which basically says, if this page, do this script.

```
var url = '\/my-page\/\?ref\=[0-999]';
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

How do I write the regex to find the number? I've been looking a many examples, but can't find one like what I'm trying to do. I've never done a regex before and am struggling to figure this out.

Why am I doing this, you might ask? Basically, we have a page with a form and some hidden fields. I need to read the cookie to fill the hidden fields. You can't read the data on the first load, so I'm using a redirect to load the query once and then redirect to a second load on the form page. This is a temporary fix until I can figure out the right way to "redirect to self" without a redirect loop happening.

Any help on the regex would be appreciated.

Comment: why a regex when you can just read the parameter directly?

Comment: @developerwjk I'm not sure I follow. There are hundreds of IDs (the 3 digit number) so I was thinking regex so that whatever number was used at the end would get picked up in the url once redirected. We have affiliates that each have an ID number they use with their referral link. Hopefully that answers your question

Comment: Use a jQuery URL Parser plugin and make your code more maintainable instead of hacking thru regexps. Parse the URL,  fetch the query string parameter and then issue the redirect. This implies more readability and maintainability.

Comment: hundred of ref values in the same url?

Comment: No, each affiliate has their own ID number and referral url with the query string at the end of the url, like the one in the example. So it could be /?ref=236 or /?ref=487, whatever the ID is of that affiliate. The only thing that changes is the number at the end, the ID number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use reg-ex here as you could just do something like:

```js
var theString = "blahblach/ ref=234";
var theNumber = theString.substring(theString.indexOf('=')+1, theString.length);
```

Comment: So "theNumber" var reads whatever string query is in the first URL and that could be passed that to the redirect URL?

Comment: theNumber will return 236 in the example string you provided above, which you can use to construct the redirect URL.

Comment: On theString, would the way to get the current query string be something like `window.location.pathname`?

Comment: var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only                    

var url      = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL

Comment: Thanks, I understood that, was asking about the method to get the query string, but I answered my own question with some further reading. I'll see if I can make your method work in jQuery.

Comment: I was able to get this working using parts of what you posted, thanks for the help. 
`var theString = $(location).attr('href');
 var theNumber = theString.substring(theString.indexOf('=')+1, theString.length);
 var url = '/newagent/?ref=' + theNumber;
 $(location).attr('href',url);`

It still needs an if/else to check and see if the query string is present, if not, just redirect without the query string. If I don't add the query string, it adds the ?ref= plus the redirect url after the "=".